# how to get cleaner url without showing params.?

Tags: grails, url-rewriting, parameters, gsp, url-mapping

i am passing many params from controller to page on post back.
so url looks horrible like-

```
http://localhost:8080/GryphonMonitor/load/getData?pageName=xref&dataGroup1=2&dbName=&dataGroup=2&tableCombo=tbl_AreaCodeListings&columns=ABBR&columnValue=&columns2=ABBR&columnValue2=&columns3=ABBR&columnValue3=
```

how to show only http://localhost:8080/GryphonMonitor/load/getData and hide rest of details?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "forward" instead of redirect :

```
forward(action: "home", params: params)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `POST` method instead. URL rewriting will not allow you to silently pass parameters, you would still need to somehow pass those through the URL.

Comment: well, i am using <g:form> which uses method "post"

Comment: Then you should POST those vars (pageName, dataGroup, etc) to your URL instead of sending them as GET vars (after the `?`). POSTing them will hide them from the URL and you can access them via the server.